# HTML FORM redirect on one input value, and process other input values

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Stuck on implementing a standard HTML form using POST method.

I have a simple HTML/PHP form (say https://example.com/dir/BBB.php) with 4 different fields:

```
<form method="post" action="<what-to-put-here>.php" target="_top">

  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." value="Input Name" required>

  <span>Code:</span><select name="code" required><option value="" disabled selected>Choose Code</option><option value='AAA'>AAA</option><br><option value='BBB'>BBB</option><br><option value='CCC'>CCC</option><br><option value='DDD'>DDD</option></select>

  <span>Start Date:</span><select name="startdt" required><option value='2019-11-29'>Fri, 29Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-27'>Wed, 27Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-26'>Tue, 26Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-25'>Mon, 25Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-22'>Fri, 22Nov19</option><br></select>

  <span>End Date:</span><select name="enddt" required><option value='2019-11-29'>Fri, 29Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-27'>Wed, 27Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-26'>Tue, 26Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-25'>Mon, 25Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-22'>Fri, 22Nov19</option><br></select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

There are TWO requirements:

1) All 4 fields are mandatory. Once the user fills-in/selects the values and hits "Submit" button, Need to receive the value of "code" from the submitted form, and then depending upon the value selected for the "code" field, it should redirect to to `https://example.com/dir/<code>.php` URL.

2) Rest of the three values submitted by the user (name, startdt and enddt) should also be received in the redirected URL (say like in a PHP variable, `$start_date= $_POST["startdt"]`)

To clearly cite an example, let's say a user is submitting the values while he is on https://example.com/dir/BBB.php, and selects/inputs the values as (name="Michael", code="DDD", startdt='2019-11-29', enddt='2019-12-01'). Then on hitting the submit button, he should be taken to https://example.com/dir/DDD.php page (as he has submitted DDD code), where the other three values (name="Michael", startdt='2019-11-29', enddt='2019-12-01') should also be available to be captured in a PHP variable.

I have tried using an intermediate file, as well as by using the onchange location feature, but unable to achieve the desired result. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is something you should do with JS. On change of the code input you change the action in the form tag

Comment: For part 2, I'd advise you to use sessions

Comment: For part 1, hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the backend code

Comment: @Cid, the 1st part is redirect. The moment I use onchange location function which automatically redirects to the new URL, the rest of the 3 values cannot be captured as the page moves. That's why I was looking for an overall method that fulfills both the requirements. I also thought of having the code as the LAST field so that other three values can be captured earlier, but I need to have "code" as the second field.

Comment: You can use $_SESSION to store values before redirection and get them on the next script.

Comment: @LelioFaieta - the problem with onchange.location is that other the 3 values are lost.

Comment: How? JS acting on change works before you submit the form and will not affect the other fields...

Comment: @LelioFaieta, that's what I seem to be missing and unable to get it implemented. I insert the name (1st field), then select the code value as DDD (2nd field), and the page redirects to DDD.php. Now the only inserted value of name is lost, and I am on page DDD with no way to retain the name (and startdt and enddt are not even inserted). What am I missing here, please?

Comment: @Aquaholic you can redirect on back-end too. This will help you to pass datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the destination of the form before you submit it you need to use JS.
Starting from this form a basic solution using jquery would be:

```js
   $('#code_switch').change(function(){
        page = $(this).val();
        page = page +'.php';
        $('#form_target').attr('action',page);
        console.log(page);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="AAA.php" target="_top" id="form_target">
    
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." value="Input Name" required>
    
      <span>Code:</span><select name="code" id="code_switch"required><option value="" disabled selected>Choose Code</option><option value='AAA'>AAA</option><br><option value='BBB'>BBB</option><br><option value='CCC'>CCC</option><br><option value='DDD'>DDD</option></select>
    
      <span>Start Date:</span><select name="startdt" required><option value='2019-11-29'>Fri, 29Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-27'>Wed, 27Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-26'>Tue, 26Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-25'>Mon, 25Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-22'>Fri, 22Nov19</option><br></select>
    
      <span>End Date:</span><select name="enddt" required><option value='2019-11-29'>Fri, 29Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-27'>Wed, 27Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-26'>Tue, 26Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-25'>Mon, 25Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-22'>Fri, 22Nov19</option><br></select>
    
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    
    </form>
```

I have added an id attribute to the form and the select for sake of simplicity. 
The form will not be submitted until you press the submit button and the destination will be based on what you selected in the code select

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thanks a lot @LelioFaieta, marking answer with +1. One note though for others which I found during my testing of the above : The page to which it is being redirected MUST exist, and its name MUST be exactly the same (case-sensitive) as in the option value. One cannot have option value as AAA and page name as aaa.php, otherwise the other field values will not be captured.